# How to reuse navigation terms multiple times

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, managed-navigation

We have a site with two different sections -- one for each of the groups in our team. We are using managed navigation and friendly urls. The two different groups have agreed on a phase taxonomy for presenting our content that will be familar across the site. Resources, pages, documents, etc. will be tagged with terms for which group it belows to and for what phase it is a part of, and from that metadata a content search web parts will be used to get the term from the url and show the correct documents. So like this.

The phase termset contains:

- Define
- Design
- Implement
- Sustain

And the groups termset contains:

- Group 1
- Group 2

I want to reuse the terms so I can have a navigation like:

- Group 1

  - Define
  - Design
  - Implement
  - Sustain
- Group 2

  - Define
  - Design
  - Implement
  - Sustain

And that will generate friendly urls like

- *site*/group1/design
- *site*/group2/design

When I try to repin or reuse the phase terms under the group terms I get an error message **Terms can not be shared multiple times in the same term set**.

How can I reuse the terms in multiple places?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe term sets used for navigation can be attached to multiple sites.  You may have to copy the terms into a new set for each site.

Comment: This isn't for use on different sites. Just different pages in the same site. It seems like a fairly common organization of information, if they can't be reused, is there some other way to accomplish this?